# Azure - Bitbucket deployment failure

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, azure, deployment, bitbucket, continuous-deployment

I have an asp.net mvc 4 website using continous deployment through Bitbucket on Windows Azure.
I needed to change the account (as it was a test at first), and redeployed using the bitbucket / Azure deployment feature.

But it failed unfortunately :(, it seems "HttpConfiguration" could not be found :O :

Here are the logs of the deployment :

```
C:\DWASFiles\Sites\mlcpending\VirtualDirectory0\site\deployments\tools\deploy.cmd
Handling .NET Web Application deployment.
D:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(1578,5): warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "System.Net.Http.Formatting, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors. [C:\DWASFiles\Sites\mlcpending\VirtualDirectory0\site\repository\BienvenueBebe\BienvenueBebe.csproj]
D:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(1578,5): warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "System.Web.Http, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors. [C:\DWASFiles\Sites\mlcpending\VirtualDirectory0\site\repository\BienvenueBebe\BienvenueBebe.csproj]
D:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(1578,5): warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "System.Web.Http.WebHost, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors. [C:\DWASFiles\Sites\mlcpending\VirtualDirectory0\site\repository\BienvenueBebe\BienvenueBebe.csproj]
App_Start\WebApiConfig.cs(10,37): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'HttpConfiguration' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [C:\DWASFiles\Sites\mlcpending\VirtualDirectory0\site\repository\BienvenueBebe\BienvenueBebe.csproj]
An error has occurred during web site deployment.
Handling .NET Web Application deployment.
D:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(1578,5): warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "System.Net.Http.Formatting, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors. [C:\DWASFiles\Sites\mlcpending\VirtualDirectory0\site\repository\BienvenueBebe\BienvenueBebe.csproj]
D:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(1578,5): warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "System.Web.Http, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors. [C:\DWASFiles\Sites\mlcpending\VirtualDirectory0\site\repository\BienvenueBebe\BienvenueBebe.csproj]
D:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(1578,5): warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "System.Web.Http.WebHost, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors. [C:\DWASFiles\Sites\mlcpending\VirtualDirectory0\site\repository\BienvenueBebe\BienvenueBebe.csproj]
App_Start\WebApiConfig.cs(10,37): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'HttpConfiguration' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [C:\DWASFiles\Sites\mlcpending\VirtualDirectory0\site\repository\BienvenueBebe\BienvenueBebe.csproj]
An error has occurred during web site deployment.
D:\kuduservice\wwwroot\bin\scripts\starter.cmd C:\DWASFiles\Sites\mlcpending\VirtualDirectory0\site\deployments\tools\deploy.cmd
```

Anyone having these issues too ?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your solution may not have NuGet enabled. Try right clicking on your solution in VS to enable that, commit the change and then push again.

But I doubt this is related to changing the Bitbucket account.